# Резкий и кривой угол с одной стороны

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кривой угол у блока только с одной стороны используя только CSS и HTML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [эффект загнутого уголка на CSS](https://webformyself.com/sozdajte-prostoj-effekt-zagnutogo-ugolka-na-css/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для такой примитивной задачи, вполне подойдут линейные градиенты:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 512px;
  width: 363px;
  padding: 135px 0 34px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: 
    /* Уголок */
    0 0 / 69px 76px linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0000 0 49.5%, #3ac771 50%), 
    /* Тени уголка */
    0 0 / 70px 79px linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0000 0px 50%, #00000001 50%), 
    0 0 / 69px 78px linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0000 0 50%, #0001 50%), 
    /* Фон правее уголка */
    0 0 / 100% 100% linear-gradient(to right, #0000 0 69px, #29b961 69px), 
    /* Фон ниже уголка */
    0 0 / 100% 100% linear-gradient(to bottom, #0000 0 76px, #29b961 76px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.type { font: bold 75px/1em sans-serif; color: #fff2; }
.title { font: 28px/1.4em sans-serif; color: #fff; margin-top: -42px; }
.size { font: 28px/1em sans-serif; color: #fff6; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="type">PDF</div>
  <div class="title">Название<br>сертификата</div>
  <div class="size">4.5 MB</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приветствую) Решение на градиенте даже лучше (+)

Comment: @DeMinov, это называется "встал, чтобы водички попить на кухне" :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает как нужно , только хотелось бы узнать, как увеличить размер этого угла?

Comment: @МаксимОрлов: первые нули везде - это позиция - не трогаем. Меняем только размеры уголка и теней (в оригинале теней не было, я добавил для красоты, поэтому можно их удалить, чтобы не заморачиваться с лишними размерами). Соответственно с новыми размерами уголка меняем и начало фоновых градиентов.

Answer (score 7):

Ну или на крайний случай используйте [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
body {font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; background-color: #333;}

.file-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 350 / 500;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #29b961;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: polygon(0 30px, 30px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.file-icon::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.file-icon__exp {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(255,255,255, .45);
  margin: 30px 0 20px;
}

.file-icon__name {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.file-icon__size {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255, .45);
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-icon">
  <div class="file-icon__exp">PDF</div>
  <div class="file-icon__name">НАЗВАНИЕ СЕРТИФИКАТА</div>
  <div class="file-icon__size">4.5 MB</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо , тоже как вариант